# JavaScript: weird boolean values for []

Tags: javascript

I've been learning JavaScript for some time now and I know better than to actually rely on this kind of behavior but I'm getting curious... why does the empty array `[]` have seemingly conflicting boolean identities?

It is truthy: `[] && true` evaluates to `true` ...and yet, it is false: `[] == false` evaluates to `true`.

However, its double negation is true: `!![]` evaluates to `true`. But it's also (using loose equality) equal to its own negation: `![] == []` evaluates to `true`.

Its numeric value is falsy: `+[] && true` evaluates to `0`.

Its string representation is falsy: `[].toString() && true` evaluates to `""`.

Is there any clear reason why `[]` is such a conundrum?

Answer (score 0):

I think the results are reasonable. The only one I'm iffy on is `+[]`, but I might have that one figured out. It's like you said, loose comparison can be misleading, but it makes sense to me.

```
console.log([] && true); //true - there is an array

console.log([] == false); //true, the array is empty

console.log(![]); //false, there is an array

console.log(!![]); //true, there isn't not an array

console.log(![] == []); //true, no array is loosely like an empty array

console.log(+[]); //0, I think this converts the array to a number, 0 being the logical choice. +[1] will return "1" and +[1,2] is "NaN" - which seems to be because the conversion is no longer feasible.

console.log([].toString()); //string '', as expected - also see next example

console.log(['stuff',{}].toString()); //stuff,[object Object]
```

Comment: But that is not explanation why is that so. For example, the first one is true because each object evaluates to true (Boolean conversion). And the second one: yes, it is empty but what happen there. I think false is converted to 0.

Comment: He didn't specifically ask how the interpreter works, he just asked why `[]` evaluates strangely. I am proposing that it isn't a "conundrum" and that the results are reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a full answer, but here are some observations:

As you know there's a `Boolean` function that returns a boolean value and it accepts a parameter, thus it closely resembles casting to bool. `Boolean([])` returns `true` which explains why `[] && true` is `true`, `![]` is false and `!![]` is true.

On the other hand the `Number([])` constructor returns 0, which explains why `+[] && true` is zero.

Another thing is that `String([])` is empty string, `String(true)` is the string `"true"` and `"" && "true"` is `""` which perfectly fits into my grand scheme as you'll see below.

Now, about the curious things. Here's what I found out:

`Number(![])` is 0, `Number([])` is 0 as well. In that case `Number(![]) == Number([])` is obviously true.

`Number([])` is 0, `Number(false)` is 0, thus `Number([]) == Number(false)`.

It seems to me that whenever JS can't directly compare two objects (neither of which are strings) it casts them to numbers and then compares. If one of them is a string it always converts to string and then evaluates any functions. At least that would explain the strange behaviour you've noticed.

Answer (score 0):

> **&&**   Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise,
>   returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if
>   both operands can be converted to true; otherwise, returns false.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

In your case

```
+[] // 0 - is falsy so it will be returned
[].toString() // "" - is falsy so it will be returned
```